# error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 4: found character that cannot start any token

Tags: kubernetes

Trying to create a deployment from this yaml file. i know the general solution: check indentation and use spaces instead of tabs. it still isnt working.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: datadog-poc-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: datadog-poc
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: datadog-poc
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: datadog-poc
        image: <My-Registry>/datadog-poc
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

the error:
error: error parsing dd_poc_deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 4: found character that cannot start any token

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up tabs and whitespace. Try this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: datadog-poc-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: datadog-poc
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: datadog-poc
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: datadog-poc
        image: <My-Registry>/datadog-poc
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

yaml doesn't support tabs.  Replacing your tabs with spaces may resolve your issue

more here: [yaml.org/faq.html](http://yaml.org/faq.html)